# How to get Ajax Reponse out of callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

What I am trying to do is to get ajax `response` out of the `success` callback.

```
var form_data = new FormData($('#formDatas')[0]);

$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'/some/url/',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    data : form_data,
    success: function(response) {
      var fonts = response.fonts; 
    }
});

alert(fonts);
```

I am aware that the code above does not work since the variable is locally defined inside its own function, but how can I get it out ?

Comment: *"how can I get it out?"* - You don't. Do the work in the callback.

Comment: You could use a promise...

Comment: @TonySamperi That's still "doing the work in the callback".

Comment: Even that it would be possible to get the `font` because you use `async: false`, you should never use `async: false`.

Comment: @t.niese What's the problem using `async: false` ?

Comment: @Lindow it will completely block/freeze the browser window until the request is finished and this is in general bad for user experience. There are only a few rare cases where `async: false` might be of use, but in general you should not use it.

Comment: @t.niese alright, thanks !

Comment: `async: false` is also deprecated by browser vendors and you will see console warnings now when you use it

Comment: Note that `var` declared inside `success` will not be accessible outside of that function irregardless of asynchronicity

Comment: @charlietfl alright, I'll have to do in inside then